# Building a VS2010 solution from TFS2008

Tags: msbuild-4.0

I have a TFS 2008 Build Agent that has been used to build .Net 3.5 applications. I now have a .Net 4.0 app which i want to compile on the same build agent. I have ensured that MSBuild 4.0 is installed on there and all the required componentry is also installed, but i am getting the following `MSB4062` error when building:

> [Any CPU/Release] C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(244,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.WebApplication.Build.Tasks.GetSilverlightItemsFromProperty" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.Build.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, and that the assembly and all its dependencies are available.

I am presuming that i get this because the TFSBuild.proj gets executed by MSBuild 3.5 which in turn means my solution is compiled with MSBuild 3.5.

Am i correct with my diagnosis? Is there any way to ensure that TFS2008 uses MSBuild 4.0 for my solution? Can it be done on a single team project so that it doesn't affect any other team projects being built on the same build agent?

Note that i have checked the question [Build failing - VS2010 solution on TFS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720057/build-failing-vs2010-solution-on-tfs2008) and this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/willbar/building-net-4-0-applications-using-team-build-2008) for an old article on this.

You need to have a build agent/server dedicated to this project, and need to get it to redirect to msbuild 4.0.

> - Configure Team Build 2008 to use
>   MSBuild 4.0 instead of MSBuild 3.5. To
>   do this edit %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\TFSBuildService.exe.config
>   and set the MSBuildPath property to
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.
> - Restart the Team Foundation Build service.

Comment: Cheers Preet, that blog post never showed up in my results. Fortunately the build agent is a virtual machine so i can just clone it.